# Como fazer um GLM com n amostral diferente?

Tags: r, glm

Quero correlacional a varável número de folhas da planta com as variáveis: temperatura, tamanho da raiz, incidência solar, umidade relativa do solo e outras. Só que tenho alguns NA em quase todas as variáveis independentes e não quero excluir as linhas com NA pois meu "n" amostral ira ficar pequeno. Existe alguma forma de fazer uma GLM com n amostras diferentes?

Comment: Não, creio que não há maneira. Veja o argumento `na.action` em `help('glm')` para várias formas de lidar com valores `NA`.

Comment: Obrigado. Irei olhar sim

Comment: Não é possível rodar GLMs tradicionais com *n*s diferentes. Existem maneiras de se lidar com isso, dependendo de como são seus dados, mas isso foge do escopo do Stack Overflow (as questões aqui devem ser específicas sobre programação). Se consegue ler e escrever em inglês, pergunte no [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), o site do Stack Exchange voltado para análise estatística.

Comment: obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 3):

Não é possível. Um modelo linear generalizado é a relação entre o vetor de respostas **Y** e a matriz de delineamento **X** representada na fórmula abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por definição, **X** não pode possuir dados faltantes. Isso se deve ao fato da estimação do vetor de parâmetros **beta** ser definida a partir da maximização da verossimilhança dos dados, que dependem diretamente deles estarem completos. Ou seja, se há dados faltantes, não é possível estimar os parâmetros do modelo e os respectivos erros padrão, o que inviabiliza a realização das inferências adequadas.

Comment: Obrigado. O que você me recomenda nesse caso? como ja falei se retirar os NA's fico com n amostral pequeno. Ha algum outro teste estatístico que eu possa utilizar?